# MOODLE (PHP) Quiz Template only giving partial output

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, moodle

I have a quiz question template that I'm trying to build from a MySQL table:

**MYSQL TABLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE `testbank` (
  `line` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `process` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `question` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ans1` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ans2` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ans3` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ans4` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correct` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**SAMPLE DATA:**

```
INSERT INTO `testbank` (`line`, `process`, `question`, `reference`, `ans1`, `ans2`, `ans3`, `ans4`, `correct`) VALUES
('246.80','COLOR OF MONEY','What is your favorite color for monetary denominations?','The U.S. Mint','Blue','Green','Grey','Brown','B');
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php

session_start();
include("connectw.php");

$z = 1;

echo '<?xml version="1.0 encoding="utf-8"?>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<quiz>' . "\r\n" . "\r\n";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT line, process, question, reference, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4, TRIM(TRAILING '\r' FROM correct) AS correct FROM testbank");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo '<!-- question: ' . $z . ' -->' . "\r\n";
echo '<question type="mutlichoice">' . "\r\n";
echo '   <name>' . "\r\n";
echo '      <text>' . $row['line'] . ' ' . $row['process'] . '</text>' . "\r\n";
echo '   </name>' . "\r\n";
echo '   <questiontext format="html">' . "\r\n";
echo '   <text>' . "\r\n";
echo "      <![CDATA[(" . $row['line'] . " " . $row['process'] . ") " . $row['question'] . " <!-- " . $row['reference'] . " -->]]>" . "\r\n";
echo '   </text>' . "\r\n";
echo '   </questiontext>' . "\r\n";

echo '   <defaultgrade>1</defaultgrade>' . "\r\n";
echo '   <penalty>0.1</penalty>' . "\r\n";
echo '   <hidden>0</hidden>' . "\r\n";
echo '   <shuffleanswers>0</shuffleanswers>' . "\r\n";
echo '   <answernumbering>none</answernumbering>' . "\r\n";

        if ($row['correct'] == 'A') {$af1 = '100'; } else {$af1 = '0'; }
        if ($row['correct'] == 'B') {$af2 = '100'; } else {$af2 = '0'; }
        if ($row['correct'] == 'C') {$af3 = '100'; } else {$af3 = '0'; }
        if ($row['correct'] == 'D') {$af4 = '100'; } else {$af4 = '0'; }

echo '   <answer fraction="' . $af1 . '">' . "\r\n";
echo '      <text>' . $row['ans1'] . '</text>' . "\r\n";
echo '   </answer>' . "\r\n";
echo '   <answer fraction="' . $af2 . '">' . "\r\n";
echo '      <text>' . $row['ans2'] . '</text>' . "\r\n";
echo '   </answer>' . "\r\n";

if ($row['ans1'] == 'TRUE') {echo ''; } else {
echo '   <answer fraction="' . $af3 . '">' . "\r\n";
echo '      <text>' . $row['ans3'] . '</text>' . "\r\n";
echo '   </answer>' . "\r\n";
echo '   <answer fraction="' . $af4 . '">' . "\r\n";
echo '      <text>' . $row['ans4'] . '</text>' . "\r\n";
echo '   </answer>' . "\r\n";

}

$z = $z + 1;
echo '</question>' . "\r\n";
echo "\r\n";

}
echo '</quiz>' . "\r\n";

?>
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

While I have around 9,000 questions, I'm only getting the output of 4 records (and it starts the 5th question).

I have other code that does similar things like this and those work fine. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

One of the things I noticed is when I cut down the number of spaces before each item `echo'd` [example: `echo '        <name>'` vs. `echo '   <name>'`] it allowed more characters in... almost like it's only showing me a finite number of characters.

Besides using `mysql_query` vs. `mysqli_query`, anybody see anything that needs to change?

Comment: Please! Get rid of mixing markup + logic + data...And please do NOT use deprecated `mysql_*`

Comment: @B001 I'm not sure what you mean by `markup + logic + data` -- can you expand on what you mean? (I know what you mean by using `MySQL_*`. I'm in the process of converting files but I've got thousands to go through and I'm a one-man operation.)

Comment: I mean you will (as a developer) have a much easier life if you follow the rules of separation of concerns.... the code above is mixing html, php and mysql ..

Comment: Well, the data is in MySQL... yes. I'm using PHP to pull the data from MySQL and format it -- but not HTML. It's actually a pseudo-XML file that's being output. I'm not trying to be 'flip' here, I just don't know how to achieve this without using PHP and MySQL. The questions started out as a CSV file, how SHOULD I have formatted them for the MOODLE XML file?

Comment: _...don't know how to achieve this without using PHP and MySQL..._ You will need php and mysql...but...think about something like MVC...A must have if your application has a certain complexity.... in general using OOP is the first step..